# Synonymize [filetype], [filetypes], and [file-type], or destroy them?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-block-request

[filetype](/questions/tagged/filetype) contains 81 questions.

[filetypes](/questions/tagged/filetypes) contains 4 questions.

[file-type](/questions/tagged/file-type) contains 15 questions.

Obviously all 3 don't need to exist. They could be merged. But the real question here is: do we need this tag? I personally don't feel it's so meta-like that it should be removed, just not widely used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and synonymized [filetype](/questions/tagged/filetype) and [filetypes](/questions/tagged/filetypes)  to [file-type](/questions/tagged/file-type), and added a summary to the tag wiki.

There are similar tags, such as [file-format](/questions/tagged/file-format) and [file-extension](/questions/tagged/file-extension), but those tags have a somewhat different meaning.